# Which preposition to be used for the below statements? Of, From, or By?

Tags: prepositions

I'm confused with which preposition to be used for the following sentences. A friend of mine told me that is should be "from".

1.Those opening songs are FROM Lady Gaga.
2. Those songs are FROM Beatles."

I believe it should have been *of* or *by* because the above sentences are pertaining to songs sung by the said artists. It shows possession.

Many thanks!

Comment: *Songs by the Beatles* does not show possession. It shows that they sang the song. *From* sounds like they came from a location called The Beatles.

Comment: Yosef Baskin, so Of should have been used?

Comment: It's usually the other way round: not "songs by/of/from The Beatles", but "Beatles songs." Likewise "the orchestra played a Beethoven symphony" and not "a symphony by Beethoven".

Comment: "This song is from 'Carousel' " or "That number was from [ie played / recorded by, with the speaker addressing an audience] the Beatles" are idiomatic.